# Firebase/Flutter: reload() not refreshing user.isEmailVerified

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm sending a verification link when a user registers in the app, but when I try to create a stream that listens for when the user has clicked the verify link in the email.

I'm aware that I somehow need to refresh the user token, but I can't seem to get it to work. I thought `reload()` method was the one, but maybe I'm just not implementing it correctly.

The problem is that the Stream always returns isEmailVerified == false, only way to make it true is for the user to log out and log in again, which is something I'd like to avoid. How do I do this?

I've created this future:

```
//CHECKS IF EMAIL IS VERIFIED
  Future<bool> checkIfEmailIsVerified() async {
    FirebaseUser currUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    await currUser.reload();
    currUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    final bool flag = currUser.isEmailVerified;

    if (currUser != null) {
      return flag;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and this stream:

```
//IS EMAILVERIFIED STREAM
  Stream<EmailVerified> get emailVerified async* {
    final bool isEmailVerified = await checkIfEmailIsVerified();
    yield EmailVerified(isEmailVerified);
  }
```

Comment: what is the question

Comment: Updated my question with: "The problem is that the Stream always returns isEmailVerified == false, only way to make it true is for the user to log out and log in again, which is something I'd like to avoid. How do I do this?"

Comment: how are u sending verification link?

Comment: What is the purpose of this ? 
    `FirebaseUser currUser = await _auth.currentUser(); // setting it to current user
    await currUser.reload(); // reloading it
    currUser = await _auth.currentUser(); // then setting it again?`
Maybe remove the last assign

Comment: @PeterHaddad `await user.sendEmailVerification();` is called inside a Future that also registers the user. The email verification link is successfully sent, and when the link in the email is clicked it also works (user is now verified) but to be able to check in the frontend if the user has clicked the link, the only way I could see that was for the user to log out and log in. I would like to do this without having to log out/log in.

Comment: @TinusJackson I tried just setting it once but also didn't work. Then I tried this solution which I read on a question on GitHub to a similar issue which fixed it for them. But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it's necessary to get fresh instance of the user after reload:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user != null) {
    await user.reload();
    user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is helpful! Thanks!
I added this in a Future like this:

  Future<void> CheckUserAreVerified()async{ 
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      await user.reload();
      user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (user!.emailVerified) {
        print("emailVerifiedd  ${user.emailVerified} ");
      }
    }
  }

Comment: YESSS! God, nowhere it was explained, why the first call with reload() and emailVerified always returned false, and the second - true.

I only read things about a need to "sing out and in again", or about a need to "generate a new token", which obviously didn't explain the behavior. 

This one both explained the behavior and helped, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try using a single await over chained futures

```
FirebaseUser currUser = await _auth.currentUser().then((u) => u.reload().then((_) => _auth.currentUser()));
final bool flag = currUser.isEmailVerified;
```

Comment: Tried this, but same result (only way to refresh user token is to log out and log in again.

Comment: Not sure about "user token", the full code listing and all what's specific to that in OP, but `currUser.isEmailVerified` is indeed updated when using this code.  In terms of the title there *"Firebase/Flutter: reload() not refreshing user.isEmailVerified"* , I was able to verify this answer as the solution and seems should be marked as Accepted Answer. Saved me potentially hours, thank you

Comment: It worked!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this
**await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken(true)**

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.emailVerified == true) {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken(true); //! Must Add true
  //! TODO Other Code
}
```